# how to recursively parse tree of nested comments via selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, recursion

I need to scratch comments and replies to comments with usernames, dates from this [website](https://tengrinews.kz/kazakhstan_news/bagdat-musin-naznachen-vitse-ministrom-tsifrovogo-razvitiya-408861/)

The tree of comments sits inside a div container 'comment-list' and each comment may have a recursive structure(if has replies):

"comment-list" contains list of "comment-item".

each "comment-item" has 4 pieces: metadata(username, time),actual comment,replies

- comment-item-content:

  - metadata:

    - username
    - time when posted
  - div 'comment-text' p ACTUAL COMMENT /p

  if replies exist, repeating comment-item:

  - comment-item
  - comment-item

Here is the carcas:

```
<div class = 'tn-comment-list'>
   <div class ='tn-comment-item'>
      <div class = 'tn-comment-item-content'>
         <div class = 'tn-comment-item-content-metadata'> 
            <span class = 'tn-user-name'>username 1 </span>
            <time> july 20 2020 18:02 </time>
         </div>
         <div class = 'tn-comment-item-content-text'>
            <p> bla bla comment 1 </p>
         </div>
         <div class = 'tn-comment-item'>... </div> //reply1
         
         <div class = 'tn-comment-item'>... </div>//reply 2
         
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Instead of doing recursively, i tried to just find all the elements that are comments (comment-item) , regardless of whether they are answers or not.

```
from selenium import webdriver

news_url = 'https://tengrinews.kz/kazakhstan_news/strogiy-karantin-vvodyat-v-mangistauskoy-oblasti-408772/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(news_url)

comments_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='tn-comment-item']")
print(type(comments_list))
print('length of comments %d ' % len(comments_list))
```

The length of comments_list is 21, but i dont know how to traverse thru it. Plus, I think recursive parsing is still good idea.

How to parse it recursively and get all comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bit of fun with this!

I tried what i would normally do in c# - that is collect the list of elements, iterate through with a for each and do nested `element.find...` - but it didn't work. I don't know if it python or the site or just me but i had to do things differently.

It's recursive function built on dynamically constructing and iterating through xpaths:

```py
def PrintRecursiveComments(rootXpath, level):
    ##from the root- this is the path to element with text - there is only 1
    ##textPath = '/div[@class="tn-comment-item-content-text"]/p'
    textPath = '/div/p'
    ##from the root - this is a nested child comment
    repeatingPattern = '/div[@class="tn-comment-item"]/div[@class="tn-comment-item-content"]'

    ##get the comment blocks at this level
    comments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(rootXpath)
    if (len(comments) > 0 ):
        for i in range(len(comments)): # i know it's weird on the surface - need 'i' to iterate 
            print('   -   >  level %d', level)
            print('   -   > comments at this level %d', len(comments))
            try:
                #need to use driver - won't let me find inside comments list
                #creating format (//xpath)[i]
                commentObject = driver.find_element_by_xpath('('+ rootXpath +')' +'['+str(i+1)+']' + textPath)
                print (commentObject.text)
                #update the root to contain any children
                newrootXpath = '('+ rootXpath +')' +'['+str(i+1)+']' + repeatingPattern
                PrintRecursiveComments(newrootXpath, level+1)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print("exception occurred")
                pass
            print('') #line break
```

I left my debug lines in there as it helps with the output

Call it like this:

```py
rootList = '//div[@class="tn-comment-list"]/div[@class="tn-comment-item"]/div[@class="tn-comment-item-content"]'

PrintRecursiveComments(rootList,1)
```

FYI - need this import too:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

Finally - i noted that you can only get the text from the comments IF the comments section is expanded. You might need more steps and some syncronisation around that. Have a google for webdriverwait (loads of examples out there)

This was my output vs the site. The levels of comments look right to me:
[image: run results]

Comment: edwards - damn, i was thinking of it too! i can't get the comments secion if it's hidden....! and I DID NOT EXPAND - DID NOT CLICK ON BUTTON 'expand comments'

Comment: I didn't even know that's what the button said. I only viewed the site in Russian! For the "expand comments" did you need that webdriver wait + button click or have you got this from here?

Comment: i got it from u, i had vague feeling i should do it. but because i could see comment texts in inspector - i was thinking they are accessible thru webdriver.. turns out not!

Comment: i see there is typo in print(---> 'level %d' , level) , last level should be i

Comment: Print lines are only for debug - shouldn't make too much difference to the output. The level is the depth aand i is the iteration through each message. The change to use (i) was the last thing that made it work. It doesn't have a debug line as it clicked into place after it.  I didnt know what output you needed but it's all for you mate so modify as you need :-)

Comment: thx u, i wasted about 6h, dont know how i would code and work without stackoverflow!

Comment: hey, i have another bug here the comments are empty.. i only see the debug lines "level %d... " as i can't click on 'show comments' button